# Why does Eclipse reference a 1.4 JRE?

Tags: java, eclipse

When attempting to create a new Java Project, eclipse is telling me that the workspace is using a 1.4 JRE (see screenshot). Any ideas why it might be saying this? I don't even *have* a 1.4 JRE installed on my machine.

I'm using GGTS 3.5.1 on Juno 3.8.2.

My GGTS.ini (eclipse.ini) file has:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_15/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe Juno can't handle/identify Java8 correctly and somehow mistakes it for/defaults to Java4? Just a wild guess, though. Edit: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947844/why-wont-eclipse-switch-the-compiler-to-java-8

Comment: 1.4?  http://i.imgur.com/BO7rmKK.jpg

Comment: Why don't you use a newer Eclipse ? Mars is coming in a  week and I've been using the RCs and they are pretty stable too.

Comment: There is nothing in your screenshot related to an 1.4 JRE. So, what is your question?

Comment: @JBNizet First screenshot shows eclipse detects a 1.4 JRE even though the rest of the screenshots show OP doesn't have one....

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm on a train, and only one of the screenshots was loaded, the other ones staying invisible.

Comment: Indeed, Kepler SR2 is the first release that properly supports Java 8, *if* you add the extra patches for it. You really should just switch to Luna SR2 at this point, or Mars on the 24th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Marvin mentioned in the comments above, Eclipse Juno is not compatible with JDK 1.8. It might be a bug that Eclipse interprets JDK 1.8 as 1.4, but I suspect you can work around it by either removing the 1.8 from your list of installed JREs or updating to a recent version of Eclipse/Grails Tool Suite (Juno is quite old, very soon 3 full releases behind and the latest version of GGTS is based on Eclipse 4.4).