# Scala - build with hashmap

Tags: java, scala

I made hashmap that contains varous type of data in java and would like to pass it to scala.

In java

```
HashMap<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

In scala

```
def myApp(myMap: HashMap[String, Any]) // Object -> Any
```

The hashmap was passed well and used it like below.

```
val aValue = myMap.getOrDefault("A", "a").asInstanceOf[String]
val bValue = myMap.getOrDefault("B", new Hashmap[String, String]).asInstanceOf[ Hashmap[String, String]]
```

It wored as I expected, BUT when I tried to build it with gradle to make a jar. It came with this error.

```
[ant:scalac] myApp.scala:44: error: value getOrDefault is not a member of java.util.HashMap[String, Any]
[ant:scalac]  Note: implicit method myEncoder is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[ant:scalac]         val aValue = myMap.getOrDefault("A", "a").asInstanceOf[String]
[ant:scalac]                            ^
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? `getOrDefault` is from Java 8

Comment: how should I change my java version from eclipse?

Comment: I changed project > java Compiler > jdk compliance > JDK compliance as 1.8, but got still same error.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24947844/5743988)

Comment: I did, but got same error.. thanks tho

Comment: Are you building with Gradle from Eclipse or from command line?

Comment: On eclipse. for double check, i changed JAVA_HOME path as jdk 1.8, but still same error.

Comment: I figured it out. It ran with 'gradle wrapper's default' . I changed it from 'run as' > 'gradle build' > arguamets > worksapce JRE as jdk 1.8. Now need to find out where gradle wrapper's default is set and how to change. thanks :)

Comment: It's on build.gradle. Everythings works well. you saved me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like this below:

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.mutable._

def myApp(myMap: java.util.HashMap[String, Any])=

{

val scalaHashMap=myMap.asScala

}
```