# Eclipse JDK 1.8 not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed JDK 1.8. When I look at Preferences > Java > Installed JREs, the only thing on the list is jdk1.8.0_60.

But when I look at Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments, I don't see anything above JavaSE-1.7. None of my projects can use JDK 1.8.

I've tried Googling for an answer to this, but all I get are pages that talk about how to install JDK 1.8. I've also tried reinstalling JDK 1.8 and Eclipse and that didn't work. I have no idea what could possibly be wrong.

Comment: What compiler do you see being used? Preferences > Java > Compiler.

Comment: 1.7 and when I click on the down arrow, there is no 1.8.

Comment: Did your jdk and jre both installed properly? What do you see in your control panel > java > view? Also make sure your JAVA_HOME is setup properly once jdk is installed.

Comment: In Control Panel, it says that my platform is 1.8. Also tried configuring JAVA_HOME and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer here: [Programming Java 8 in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295275/programming-java-8-in-eclipse)

"I just went to the Eclipse Marketplace from inside of Eclipse (Help/Eclipse Marketplace...) and installed the "Java 8 support for Eclipse Kepler SR2""

Comment: This is rather old, you would do better to move to the current version of Eclipse (Eclipse Mars) which has improved Java 8 support.